# Replacing default TomcatServerFactory

Tags: grails

I'm want to change the default org.grails.plugins.tomcat.TomcatServerFactory 
user by grails run-app with a mine implementation but I was not able to do it.

Looking at source (grails 2.0.4) i see in run-app script

grails-core/scripts/_GrailsRun.groovy

```
93    String defaultServer = "org.grails.plugins.tomcat.TomcatServerFactory"
94    def containerClass = getPropertyValue("grails.server.factory", defaultServer)
```

I have tried to set grails.server.factory with mine class but it simply seems ignored by grails.

I have tested putting the configurazione in BuildConfing or passing it with -D running grails but without success.

What's my mistake?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Tomcat plugin forces the value after yours is read from the commandline in its `scripts/_Events.groovy`

You can get it to work by setting it in an event handler that fires after the Tomcat plugin's, but before it's used, e.g.

```
eventRunAppStart = {
   System.setProperty 'grails.server.factory', 'my.class.name'
}
```

If you want to keep it dynamic you could set its value to your own system property, e.g.

```
eventRunAppStart = {
   System.setProperty 'grails.server.factory',
         System.getProperty('my.grails.server.factory')
}
```

and change the run-app call to

```
grails -Dmy.grails.server.factory=my.class.name run-app
```